# Safari and the way it calculates screen size

Tags: jquery, safari

I know the mods are going to mark this down and shoot me. But here we go.

I read an article once, and can only remember bits of it. It was in regards to the way (excuse the terminology it may be incorrect) safari calculates image size or screen render size (or something) of the document after the dom (I think) is loaded compared to other browsers which do this before.

Now I wish I could find this article as it may help serval scripts I have seen during my years which fail on safari which I believe is due to this way that it works. I spent 1-month research this once and hence came across that article but it was late and I lost it :(

here is an example of a script that fails on safari. as you can see after loading the page jumps down in safari, whereas other browsers it works fine.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

It's a chat plugin and as you can see the page jumps down when the page is loaded.

http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/support-chat-php-live-chat-with-desktop-and-mobile-app/full_screen_preview/15044181?_ga=2.224366171.1564047310.1534235172-1374281836.1534235172&_gac=1.246621488.1534235233.EAIaIQobChMI_fS8ro_s3AIVhZGPCh1IqgWKEAAYASAAEgKs2PD_BwE

Script which initlises the plugin:

```
     var cbuser = {name: '', email: '', message: ''}, 
 access_token = 'otFcAY6Cffffk7JBfXRrzIsg', 
 cburl = '//www.domain.com/chat/';
 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + cburl + 'assets/cmodule-chat/js/chatbull-init.js"></' + 'script>');
```

Comment: Where is the script that fails in safari?

Comment: i posted the script which binds the script to the page. i can not post the whole application. This one is a angular chat app. but i do see it being an issue with the way the script is loaded and at what time.